# Notepad++ how to replace with random positions of text

Tags: string, xml-parsing, notepad++

I wanna replace few strings in my XML, but i didn't know, how to "TAG?" strings. I lost my passwords from Opera, but i got old copy from Mozilla but they was at different groups and parses so i wanna change they and import to Opera. I didnt know posibilites of Notepad, only i know how working \n \t \r and i find
on internet only [^"]* that i know how working

Passwords from Mozilla in XML:

```
<entry host="http://auth.opera.com" user="myrandommail@gmail.com" password="RandomPassword123" formSubmitURL="https://auth.opera.com/account/authenticate/,
```

replace to:

Passwords from Opera in CSV (name,url,username,password,note,):

```
auth.opera.com,https://auth.opera.com/account/authenticate/,myrandommail@gmail.com,RandomPassword123,
```

Final effect what i trying to do from:

```
<entry host="http://[1^"]*" user="[2^"]*" password="[3^"]*" formSubmitURL="[4^"]*,
```

replace to

```
[1^"]*,[4^"],[2^"]*,[3^"]*,
```

I posted [1^"]* like a TAG of parse and selected classes to pharse [^"]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture groups are written with parenthesis and are used in the replacement part with `$n` where `n` is the number of the group.

For your example, you should use:

- Find what: `<entry host="http://([^"]*)" user="([^"]*)" password="([^"]*)" formSubmitURL="([^"]*),`
- Replace with: `$1,$4,$2,$3`